# What is pry doing that allows this rspec to pass?

Tags: ruby, rspec, pry

When I run this code through its test suite, the self.reset_all method fails (as it should).  When I insert a binding.pry in the method, it tells me the array is empty and the test passes.

```
require "pry"

class Owner
  attr_reader :species

  def initialize(species)
    @species = species
  end

  def self.all
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self)
  end

  def self.reset_all
    binding.pry
    self.all.to_a
  end

  def self.count
    all.count
  end
end
```

Here are the tests:

```
describe Owner do
  let(:owner) { Owner.new("human") }

  describe 'Class methods' do
    it "keeps track of the owners that have been created" do
      expect(Owner.all).to include(owner)
    end

    it "can reset the owners that have been created" do
      Owner.reset_all
      expect(Owner.count).to eq(0)
    end

    it "can count how many owners have been created" do
      Owner.reset_all
      Owner.new("human")
      expect(Owner.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end 
end
```

I get green tests with the binding.pry, and failing without.

Comment: Why would calling `ObjectSpace.each_object(Owner).to_a` change the number of `Owner` objects?

Comment: It doesn't work.  My code is wrong. But pry makes the test pass.  Why? Hence the question...   (I reworded the question so it doesn't seem like I assumed the code was correct.)

Comment: It's probably because whatever starts pry is initiating a garbage collection sweep, which is causing some leftover `Owner` instances to be destroyed. This is the weirdness of messing with `ObjectSpace`